# blockUI not working with showModalDialog

Tags: jquery, blockui, showmodaldialog, jquery-blockui

How do I get the blockUI overlay to display before the showModalDialog is called?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.blockUI({ message: '' });    
    window.showModalDialog("http://www.google.com");
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dTG82/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the animation the `$.blockUI` function is not synchronous. You will have to wait for the animation to complete, or set `fadeIn: 0`.

```
$.blockUI({ message: '', fadeIn: 0 });
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dTG82/3/)

Answer (score 0):

There could be so many answers to this question - but one obvious problem is that you call unblockUI immediately - and window.showModalDialog won't be a blocking method (as javascript doesn't support them) - it will return immediately.

You should call unblockUI in the close handler of the modal dialog.

All this of course assumes the methods are working as advertised in the first place.

Comment: Calling unblockUI immediately isn't the problem.  You can see the unblockUI animation run after the popup is closed.

Comment: Ah sorry!  I didn't realise this was some evil IE only method that in fact does block.

Comment: Performs the same way in Firefox too.